# Content moving with editable division

Tags: html, css

What I have is several editable divisions, the user may be able to edit the division with a few words or an entire paragraph.  The problem is, if they exceed one line of the division's width the content of the entire page won't move down to accommodate it, instead the newly edited text just sits above anything it overlaps (I'm not using Z-Index).

How can I make the division push the rest of the page down as it's being edited and after it's been edited and "Saved"

My Divisions CSS is:

```
.information {
    font-size: 12pt;
    color: red;
    background-color: transparent;
    max-width: 700px;
}
```

And when you click on the division my jquery adds this class to it...

```
.editDivOn {
    background-color: lightpink;
    color: black;
    width: 260px;
    font-size: 12pt;
}
```

code snippet

```
<tr>
    <td>
        <div>What are the key dates for your program and when do you need your audience to have all the pertinent information?</div>
        <div class=\"center-content-div\">
        <div class = 'information' contenteditable='true' id = 'key_dates' name = 'key_dates'>".stripslashes($db_obj->key_dates)."</div>
        </div>
   </td>
```

Comment: I'm guessing you have something like this? https://codepen.io/mcoker/pen/mwoKMW It seems fine to me. We shouldn't have to guess at your markup though - please provide us with a [mcve]

Comment: Here's a small snippet, I've added it to the original question.

Comment: Yes, I do, that one is working...hmmm...let me try something

Answer (score 0):

Ah, I fixed it, thanks Michael Coker.  For some reason I thought you had to use contenteditable="true" but you do not.  Adding the ="true" to it caused the entire issue.  I've removed it and it's working as intended!